# Erro ao clicar no botão em Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Olá estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em python usando tkinter mas não sei porque está a dar-me erro. Inspirei-me num exemplo.
O meu código.

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()

win.geometry("400x150")

class Application:
def __init__(self, master=None):

    self.title = Label(win,text="Please enter the username and password",font=('Helvetica',13))
    self.title.pack()

    self.suc = Label(win,font=('Helvetica',10))
    self.suc.pack()
    
    self.username = Entry(win,width=20)
    self.username.pack()

    self.password = Entry(win,show="*",width=20)
    self.password.pack()

    self.btnConfirm = Button(win, text="Enter",font=('Helvetica bold',10),command=self.enter)
    self.btnConfirm.pack()

    self.btnQuit = Button(win, text="Quit",font=('Helvetica bold',10),command=self.exit)
    self.btnQuit.pack()

def exit(self):
   win.destroy()

def enter(self):
    if username=="admin" and password=="123":
        self.suc["text"] = "Sucess"
    else:
        self.suc["text"] = "Error"

Application(win)
win.mainloop()
```

O erro que acontece ao clicar no botão Enter:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ESFA\Desktop\Project Python\index1.py", line 29, in enter
    if username=="admin" and password=="123":
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
```

Comment: esqueceu o self a frente do username e password

Comment: vou tentar isso, obrigado

Comment: no seu codigo tambem faltou usar StringVar, isso é coisa de tkinter, de uma pesquisada

Comment: ok obrigado por informar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

**Você precisa também adicionar `self._<atributo> = StringVar()` no seu construtor para `username` e `password`, a resposta do Elton Nunes tem o código completo.**

Na função `def_enter(self)` você chama os objetos `username` e `password`, mas eles não foram declarados previamente na função.

Há duas opções numa situação dessas:

- reescrever a função e passar os parâmetros `def_enter(self, username, password)`
- chamar os atributos do método construtor(`__init__`) da sua classe:
  `if self._username.get()=="admin" and self._password.get()=="123"`.

**Ao usar a segunda opção o Tkinter lerá os inputs e fará a comparação lógica corretamente.**

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar essa maneira

Comment: Editei a resposta, o Elton Nunes mostrou o que provavelmente leva ao problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei seguir as indicações mas gera outro erro.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: enter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()

win.geometry("400x150")

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self.title = Label(master,text="Please enter the username and password",font=('Helvetica',13))
        self.title.pack()

        self.suc = Label(master,font=('Helvetica',10))
        self.suc.pack()
        
        self.username_var = StringVar()
        self.username = Entry(master,width=20, textvariable=self.username_var)
        self.username.pack()

        self.password_var = StringVar()
        self.password = Entry(master,show="*",width=20, textvariable=self.password_var)
        self.password.pack()

        self.btnConfirm = Button(master, text="Enter",font=('Helvetica bold',10),command=self.enter)
        self.btnConfirm.pack()

        self.btnQuit = Button(master, text="Quit",font=('Helvetica bold',10),command=self.exit)
        self.btnQuit.pack()

    def exit(self):
       win.destroy()

    def enter(self):
        if self.username_var.get() =="admin" and self.password_var.get() =="123":
            self.suc["text"] = "Sucess"
        else:
            self.suc["text"] = "Error"

Application(win)
win.mainloop()
```